# Proof that a function is increasing in an interval around $0$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

> Show that $f(x) = \begin{cases}
>  \alpha x +x^2sin(\frac{1}{x}) &\text{if}\, x\neq 0\\
>  0&\text{if}\, x= 0\
> \end{cases}$ is increasing in some interval around $0$ if $\alpha > 1$

Proof: 
The derivative of $f$ is:
$$f'(x)= \begin{cases}\alpha+2xsin(\frac{1}{x})-cos(\frac{1}{x}) &\text{if}\ x \neq 0\\ \alpha &\text{if}\ x=0 \end{cases}$$

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}2xsin(\frac{1}{x}) = 0$,
$$\exists\delta>0  \quad\text{s.t} \quad 0<|x|<\delta \Longrightarrow \left|2xsin\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)\right| < \frac{\alpha - 1}{2}$$
$$-\frac{\alpha-1}{2}<2xsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Since $-1 \leq -cos(\frac{1}{x})$, we have
$$\alpha-1-\frac{\alpha-1}{2} < \alpha+2xsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\frac{\alpha - 1}{2}<\alpha+2xsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$\frac{\alpha - 1}{2} > 0 \Longrightarrow$ $f'(x) > 0$ for $0<|x|<\delta$ and since $f'(0) = \alpha>0$,
$$f(x) \text{ is increasing on }  (-\delta, \delta)$$

Is there anything wrong with this proof?

Comment: Use, for example, `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$.

Comment: *Is there anything wrong with this proof?*

What are your thoughts?

Comment: $f'(x)\ge a-2|x|-1,$ hence $f'(x)>0$ for $|x|<(a-1)/2$, i.e. $f(x)$ is increasing on $(-(a-1)/2,(a-1)/2)$

Comment: Yep, everything seems fine, I'd like to point out just a detail at the beginning, when you state that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=\alpha$, it could be advisable to prove this fact. I don't know if you did it on paper and did not write here. The rest I think is all correct and precise.